# Permanently change mount point of volume?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, filesystem, mount, disk-volume

I'd like to set another user's home folder to use a certain volume on my disk. To that end, I'd like to be able to mount said volume at a specific location, say, at `Users/foobar`

I can do this using the command line by running `sudo mount -t hfs /dev/disk0s4 /Users/`, however this is only a temporary solution. If I unmount and remount the disk, it will mount to its usual location in `Volumes/`

Is there some way to permanently specify the mount point of a disk?

Comment: Set an entry in: `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @user3439894 I already tried, as per the instructions [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050805062520199). However when I use the File System UUID which DiskUtility gives, an error occurs when opening the disk with `sudo mount -a`, namely `GetMasterBlock: Error 2 opening UUID=5E75BA88-7C74-34A9-8CE6-266C752CE2CA
GetMasterBlock: Error 2 opening UUID=5E75BA88-7C74-34A9-8CE6-266C752CE2CA
mount_hfs: error on mount(): error = -1.
mount_hfs: No such file or directory`

Comment: Never mind, it turns out that `mount -a` just doesn't function as expected, and that setting the entry in `/etc/fstab` works fine if you mount the disk using DiskUtility

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set an entry in `/etc/fstab` as directed [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050805062520199). To summarize.

1. Open Disk Utility, unmount the relevant volume.
2. Click on the volume you're trying to mount, and click the "info" button. Note down the drive's File System UUID, which should look something like `5E85BA88-7C74-34A9-8CE6-267C752CE2BA`. I'm just gonna use `123abc` as shorthand for it.
3. Run `sudo vifs` to safely edit `etc/fstab`, and add the following line.

   `UUID=123abc /desired/mount/path hfs rw 0 2`

   or for APFS

   `UUID=123abc /desired/mount/path apfs rw 0 2`
4. Mount the volume, the mount point should show the path you specified.

Some notes:

- The page I linked instructs you to reload `/etc/fstab` using some `niload` command. I couldn't figure out how to install whatever package that required, but the good news is that I think DiskUtility will automatically reload the file, so don't worry about that.
- Some sources will tell you to reload `etc/fstab` using the command `mount -a`. It seems like this should be a perfectly sensible way to do so, but it does not work. Don't worry if it tells you it can't mount a volume.

Comment: I suggest that you read the `man 5 fstab` manual. The fifth field in the `fstab` entry is the instruction on whether you allow the filesystem to be dumped (crippled in macOS, 0 would be a better choice). The sixth field is used to determine the order in which `fsck` is run.

Comment: Editing of fstab is preferably done with `sudo vifs`!

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, I'll edit my answer to include it tomorrow

Comment: Had no joy with this but what did work for me was to write an Applescript where I pass the path using the hdiutil command. I then save as an Application and run on startup from my User setting in System Preferences. Syntax is: ```hdiutil mount -mountpoint /path/to/mountpoint <named.dmg>```

Comment: Thanks! I was so worried about this, in my case my hard drive is APFS so I edited vifs with `UUID=123abc /desired/mount/path apfs rw 1 2 ` and it worked, I have no idea what I am doing but it worked. The main reason I did this was to have that folder be *case sensitive* for runing docker with volumes... problem solved.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't copy the UUID from the window that `diskutil` pops up, but you can copy it if you go in Terminal and run `diskutil info Kingston32` where `Kingston32` is the name of the drive.

Comment: If you select the field and press CMD+C it *will* copy it.

Comment: **Note:** if there are *spaces* inside the mount path, then those need to be represented with the escaped code `\040`. E.g. *"/path/to/my volume"* must be `/path/to/my\040volume`. Otherwise it will fail silently (to actually see the mounting error run `mount -a` in the terminal).

Comment: The link in the opening sentence (http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050805062520199) is broken. That's a shame because it's the only substantive document related to `/etc/fstab` referenced here (and `man fstab` is pathetically outdated).

Answer (score 3):

In Disk Utility right tap on the APFS volume and click "Rename"

[image]

Now opening (mounting) the volume via Finder will mount it to /Volumes/home or whatever new name you give it.

Comment: In my case, after "Rename", I got "/Volumes/newname 1", I needed to do a remount. Unmount and mount, then it is "/Volumes/newname".

Comment: The OP asked to change the mountpoint, not the mount name.  This will change the name but it will still end up in /Volumes.