# What happens to existing files when changing the mount points of volumes?

Tags: macos, command-line, external-disk, mount

On 7/17/17 @bingbomboom asked [this question about creating a permanent `/etc/fstab` entry for an external drive.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291149/permanently-change-mount-point-of-volume) My head spun thinking about this next question. Instead of hijacking its thread, I'm starting fresh. I'm not focusing on re-establishing connectivity for the external drive—I'm wondering about what happens to existing files on the internal drive.

Suppose I have an internal drive on an iMac for my `Documents` with a file `int.txt.` I have an external drive with a file `ext.txt,` at its root. Both files are accessible.

If I mount the external drive's root at my internal drive's `Documents` location, what happens to `int.txt`? It's an interesting grey area to me that makes my head spin. The file `int.txt` used to be in the `Documents` folder, but if I point to `Documents` to see what's there, MacOS now logically points to the root of the external drive and my brain tells me `int.txt` will disappear and I'll only be able to see `ext.txt`.

Meanwhile, I can't imagine `int.txt` quietly *disappears* as in *it gets deleted,* so it has to be safe, somewhere, but… where?

Does it go into some form of digital limbo? How do I access it now?

Then, when I unmount the directory, will `int.txt` still be there?

Something tells me that a particular instance of the `ls` or `cp` or `mv` commands invoke the file's physical location and not its logical location, and that that *logical vs. physical difference* is the additional awareness that will stop my head from spinning.

I'm just looking for someone smarter than me to set me straight. Thanks.

Comment: How deep into Unix file handling do you want to go? At a surface level things are very simple and I’ve answered that. The only wrinkle is if you want to consider what happens if a program has a file open and then you use another process to change the file (say `rm` or mount over the directory).

Comment: What happens to `int.txt` depends on whether the `union` option is specified when mounting. When I tested with the `union` option using APFS volumes, I was able to read and remove `int.txt`, but was not able to write to `int.txt`. Attempting a write resulted in the creation of a new `int.txt` file on the external drive. This new file then masked the `int.txt` file on the internal drive.

Answer (score 1):

When you mount a new file system over an existing path everything on the previous path still exists, but is not accessible until you remove the mount.

I’m not entirely sure what your deeper question or missing part is, but the mounting process is clear and basic. As an analogy, think of a paper chessboard and post it notes that cover 4 squares. You can write whatever you want on the board. For those four squares (Documents in your case), when you mount the post it note on top, you can’t directly see or access the old scribbling until you remove the post it note. Whatever is on the note or gets written on the post it note stays on that note and doesn’t change what’s underneath.